# Kentico Web Part Design view

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I have followed the following tutorial to create Kentico Web part
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Creating+new+web+parts
I am using WebApplicaiton project and my Code behind file is as below.

```
public partial class DashBoard :   CMSAbstractWebPart
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

My ASCX file is as below.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DashBoard.ascx.cs" Inherits=" CMSWebParts.ABC.DashBoard" %>
<div>
  <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id=""></asp:dropdownlist>
</div>
```

The problem is i could view the design or split view in visual studio. I am using visual studio 2015.

[image]

How can i change source view to design view.

Comment: Not sure I've usderstood your issue... So you want to switch to Design view for your custom web part, correct? What happens when you click on Design button from your screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Nothing happen and stays in source view.

Comment: This has to be VS issue as I'm able to switch to design view in Kentico projects.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot I can see you have not mentioned id for DropDownList i.e. id=""

if you leave it empty and try to switch in design view it'll show you an error as below.
[Error creating control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkzT5.png)

if you give an id here then you should go without any issue.